# Is it ok to use cable with a distorted sheath?

Tags: wiring

I’ve been doing wiring with nmd90 14/2. At one point I noticed a small section of the wire (more specific, then outer sheath) is somewhat distorted. At first I thought it might have been just how I pulled. No as I continue to string more wire I’m seeing it more often.

I went to the spool to check wire that I had not yet pulled, and see that the sheath is like this right from the spool. I’m half way through a 250’ spool and as I work, I start questioning if there are safety concern.

Attached is a picture, although somewhat hard to see. It’s like the outer sheath isn’t formed around the wires. Other than that, the sheath is normal. It looks like this distortion is about every 10 to 15 feet.

Should this be something to worry about?

[image]

Comment: Is the cable UL listed? Well, CSA-listed?

Answer (score 2):

You can massage it with your fingers to straighten it out, and make sure when you nail or clamp it that it is flat and not on edge.

As long as it is not cut or chafed or bent sharply it should be fine.

Although it suggests something happened at the factory or in storage, it is still correctly insulated.

To be certain you could call the manufacturer and ask them if there is a recall for that production.

Comment: While it doesn't seem to be an issue, @Oldoldhouseguy I'd suggest calling the company about it anyway. They may decide to do you right and send out some replacement. Can't happen if you don't ask...